# How to iterate JSON object using right side term

Tags: json, loops

Lets say I have a JSON object like:

```
var objDBandIDs = {"vcFirstName":"enFN"
                    ,"vcSurName":"enSN"
                        ,"vcSex":["rdoM", "rdoF"]
                  ,"intEmployed":"enEmp"
                    ,"vcAddress":"enADR"};
```

In JavaScript I can iterate through this object using:

```
for( var strKey in objDBandIDs ) {
    var rightSide = objDBandIDs[strKey];
    ...
}
```

Where **strKey** is the label e.g. **vcFirstName**, rightSide would be **enFN**.

Is there a way to create a loop that instead of the **left** as an iterator, the **right** side is used to iterate through the JSON?

Comment: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the value as the key because values, unlike keys, may not be unique.

You can loop through *just* the values by looping through the result of [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values):

```
for (const value of Object.values(objDBandIDs)) {
    // ...
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const objDBandIDs = {
    "vcFirstName": "enFN",
    "vcSurName": "enSN",
    "vcSex": ["rdoM", "rdoF"],
    "intEmployed": "enEmp",
    "vcAddress": "enADR"
};
for (const value of Object.values(objDBandIDs)) {
    console.log(value);
}
```

Or you can loop through *both* using the result of [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries):

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(objDBandIDs)) {
    // ...
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const objDBandIDs = {
    "vcFirstName": "enFN",
    "vcSurName": "enSN",
    "vcSex": ["rdoM", "rdoF"],
    "intEmployed": "enEmp",
    "vcAddress": "enADR"
};
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(objDBandIDs)) {
    console.log(key, value);
}
```

In both cases, you don't *have* to use a `for..of` loop, you can use any array looping mechanism (see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476) for options).